# Button text is excluded from in-page search - is there a clean way to simulate it?

Tags: css, search, browser

It seems that browsers (FF, Chrome at least) don't include button text in their in-page search. Is there a standard idiom or clean way to simulate this? I expect there's some creative CSS hack to make this work. A want a cross-browser solution which is as clean as possible.

**update:** This happens when the button is using <input> markup.

Comment: Are you using <button>s or input[type=submit/image]? Because just for argument's sake, I changed the _Post your answer_ button on this page from an input to a button using the web inspector, and when it was an input, Chrome wouldn't pick it up, but it would when it was a button.

Comment: @Tyssen: the button is <input type="submit" value="The text" />, good point.

Comment: Seems to me that changing to buttons would be the best option. If a browser doesn't search a submit input by default, I doubt there's any CSS that could make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the button text being searched was very important and could not be left out, you might consider adding it beside the button and then naming the button something simple, like "Go!".

Ex.

```
<p style="float etc.">Descriptive Text</p> <button type="button">Go!</button>
```

Comment: It's considered bad practice to have buttons/links whose text doesn't give enough context to make sense on its own (especially for accessibility purposes). I wonder about having the descriptive text too but hiding it?

Comment: true @Draemon. `<button>` does accept a `title` attribute, so one could be added for those who need the info read out to them via screen reader.  The title could also be used for a tooltip.